# How can I configure an edge trigger on click?

Tags: compiz, system-settings

I would like to set my edge binding to require a click.

For example, I currently have the corners of my screen trigger the "scale" plugin.

I would like to set Compiz so that I go to the corner and click to mouse to activate the scale plugin.

I've already tried to set the "Initiate Window Picker" setting (with the mouse icon) to "BottomLeftEdge" and "Button1", for example.

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. In ccsm->commands I bound a custom command to [mouse icon] TopEdge|Button3 and it works. 
I do this in Lucid (compiz 0.8.4 vs compiz 0.9.4). The newer compiz is known to be buggy, to downgrade read on [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-downgrade-to-compiz-086-in.html). If not definitely file a bug in launchpad (`ubuntu-bug compiz`).